Pandas timedelta in List Comprehension
I am attempting to create a new if-else column in a df with a list comprehension:
df['col'] = ['y' if (x - df['a']).dt.days < 365 else 'n' for x in df['b']]

Columns A & B are datetimes.  If they are less than 365 apart, the 'col' will return a y flag, else an n flag.  This code returns the following error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
I can be successful doing this in two steps:
df['col'] = (df['b'] - df['a']).dt.days
df['col'] = ['y' if x < 365 else 'n' for x in df['col']]

Could someone enlighten me on why the list comprehension is not working, and/or how to fix it?

Can you please provide a reproducible example of df?

Most likely: df['col'] = np.where((df['b'] - df['a']).dt.days < 365, 'y', 'n')

You'd like to calculate row-wise difference between "a" and "b", and apply a condition on the resulting value. When you do x-df["a"], it produces the current row of "b" with all rows of "a" producing the series of equal length. (imagine doing df.iloc[0, "b"] - df["a"]). When you apply <365, it will produce a boolean series but the series itself does not have any boolean property.  Therefore the error got raised.

Thanks hteza.  I loosely grasp the difference in the series types and why they are not compatible, and guess i just don't have enough experience to know what to expect as outputs.  Changing the comprehension to the following makes it work in one line: as a comprehension
df['col'] = ['y' if x < 365 else 'n' for x in (df['b'] - df['a']).dt.days]
